# Why my longtable is throwing Underfull \vbox (badness 10000)

Tags: longtable, badness

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ | >{\RaggedRight}p{3cm} | >{\RaggedRight}p{5.0cm} | }

        \hline
        Cor                          & Branco \\
        \hline

\end{longtable} \end{document}
```

The log is:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 190
 []
```

The line 190 is `\end{longtable}`

[image]

---

## Update

I took this other example from [How to make a table on more than one page by using the table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165793/how-to-make-a-table-on-more-than-one-page-by-using-the-table-environment)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\label{tab:daypack}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|@{}|cX@{}|}
\caption{Example of an table}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\[6pt]
\midrule
\endhead

\hline
$R$ & This is an example sentence \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

And it is also having the same warning on line 196, but if I comment the `\hline` the warning stops:

[image]

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 196
 []
```

Comment: If I add `\end{document}` (;-)) and compile this, I get the line warning at `21`, so whatever you do, it's different if the warning occurs for line 190 ...

Comment: Without showing at least line 190, whaht can you hope for?

Comment: I am saying to you on the question, `The line 190 is \end{longtable}`. I commented out everything on the file and created the presented example on the question starting at line 170, therefore the example has 20 lines, so 170 + 20 = 190, which is the line where `\end{longtable}` is on

Comment: it would have been better ti show the warning as generated from the posted code (with line 21) But no harm done...

Comment: Sorry for it. As tt seemed confusing, for the future I will keep in mind to run the code from files starting on the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is being throw because there is a `\hline` directly after the table header. This should not do the warning anymore:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ | >{\RaggedRight}p{3cm} | >{\RaggedRight}p{5.0cm} | }

        % \hline % <====== This is the line causing the warning
        Cor                          & Branco \\
        \hline

\end{longtable} \end{document}
```

However this does not fix the problem of having correctly a line placed at the top of the table:

[image]

But the table presented by [@Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908) on the question [How to auto adjust my last table column width, and why is there Underfull \vbox badness on this table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387238/how-to-auto-adjust-my-last-table-column-width-and-why-is-there-underfull-vbox) is correctlly being rendered with no warning at all:

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
a5paper,
twoside
]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{3cm}|>{\arraybackslash}X|}
    \caption{Formatação do texto}
    \label{tab:table} \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\tablename~\thetable}: Formatação do texto (continued)\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize to be continued}
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
    Tamanho da fonte & 10,5 para o texto incluindo os títulos das seções e subseções.
                       As citações com mais de três linhas as legendas das ilustrações
                       e tabelas, fonte 9,5.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]