# Why several longtables are throwing bad box warning when there is a \hline on its top?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable, warnings, badness

I spend some hours today trying to find a longtable implementation which does not throw warnings when there is a `\hline` on its top header. For example:

So far the only table I could find out which was able to not throw warnings when there is a `\hline` on its top, was the table presented by [@Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908) as an answer on the question [How to auto adjust my last table column width, and why is there Underfull \vbox badness on this table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387238/how-to-auto-adjust-my-last-table-column-width-and-why-is-there-underfull-vbox)

This bellow is modification to that table, which I think is better to understand its code as I grouped related things together:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{3cm}|>{\arraybackslash}X|}

    \caption{Formatação do texto}
    \label{tab:a_table_formatacao_de_texto} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tablename~\thetable: Formatação do texto (continued)} \\
    \hline
    \endhead

    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize to be continued}
    \endfoot

    \hline
    \endlastfoot

    Cor                          & Branco -                              \\ \hline
    Formato do papel             & A5                                    \\ \hline
    Gramatura                    & 75                                    \\ \hline
    Cabeçalho                    & 0,7                                   \\ \hline
    Impressão                    & Frente e verso                        \\ \hline
    Margens                      & Espelhadas: superior 2, Inferior: 1,5 \\ \hline
    Cabeçalho                    & 0,7                                   \\ \hline
    Rodapé                       & 0,7                                   \\ \hline
    Paginação                    & Externa                               \\ \hline
    Alinhamento vertical         & Superior                              \\ \hline
    Cabeçalho                    & 0,7                                   \\ \hline
    Alinhamento do texto         & Justificado                           \\ \hline
    Cor                          & Branco -                              \\ \hline
    Formato do papel             & A5                                    \\ \hline
    Cabeçalho                    & 0,7                                   \\ \hline
    Gramatura                    & 75                                    \\ \hline
    Impressão                    & Frente e verso                        \\ \hline
    Margens                      & Espelhadas: superior 2, Inferior: 1,5 \\ \hline
    Rodapé                       & 0,7                                   \\ \hline
    Paginação                    & Externa                               \\ \hline
    Alinhamento vertical         & Superior                              \\ \hline
    Alinhamento do texto         & Justificado                           \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This table version is throwing no warnings/badboxes at all and has correctly its header with lines on its upper side:

[image]

However as learned on the question [Why my longtable is throwing Underfull \vbox (badness 10000)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387689/why-my-longtable-is-throwing-underfull-vbox-badness-10000) several longtables as:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
% \usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ | >{\RaggedRight}p{3cm} | >{\RaggedRight}p{5.0cm} | }

        \hline % <====== This is the line causing the warning
        Cor                          & Branco \\
        \hline

\end{longtable} \end{document}
```

Are causing bad boxes warnings if there is a `\hline` on its top:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 21
 []
```

[image]

But their warning is fixed by commenting out the line `\hline % <====== This is the line causing the warning`, however the table is rendered without its top line:

[image]

Why these longtables are throwing the `bad box` warning when there is a `\hline` on its top?

Comment: The top line shold be within the first head. If you write `\hline \endfirsthead`, there's no bad box.

Comment: Or `\hline\endhead` if you don't need a different one for the first page.